No-show of one person in multiple person booking
What happens if a single person doesn't show for a flight on a multiple person booking?
I reckon the airline would cancel the return flight for the no-show person, but would they also cancel every body else's trips?
Can the airline cancel the whole trip for everybody (including return flights)?
I see this question where someone could no-show on Blue Air without consequences to his fellow travel companions on the same booking. However, the answer has no explanation and I wonder if this is the case of BlueAir or if there's a general aviation rule governing cases like this.
Depending on the answer I would consider making multiple bookings for multiple people in some situations.

Personally: I do not see problem (I got such case several times, and I also go to airport, send baggage and enter in the lounge independently to other people on same booking). -- There are many reasons, e.g. health, to block one person.

That is surprising specially because of the Positive Passenger/Bag Matching rule. I assume you are only sending baggage in domestic flights. I also wonder where?

No. I send my baggage only, and my check-in, my check of ID. Staff often ask about other people, but when I say "they come later" they have absolutely no problem (so I assume they would like earlier if somebody will not travel together, so that they can sell seat or cargo)


Can the airline cancel the whole trip for everybody (including return flights)?

I never saw or heard that, so I don't think any airline would cancel the whole trip for everybody. However, it may increase the cost to other passengers if the multiple person booking gave some discount, e.g. see https://www.delta.com/us/en/special-circumstances/group-travel:

If your group does not meet the minimum of 10 or individual members do not travel with the group, (a) the deposit will be forfeited and (b) passengers will be considered individual travelers and must be ticketed at the applicable fare.

